# Boot camp install of Windows issue, no bootable devices

Tags: bootcamp, windows, startup, dual-boot, bootable-disk

So I have a 2010 15" macbook pro (MBP6,1) and I replaced the optical drive with a hard disk. I wanted to install windows 7 on the hard disk with boot camp with a USB and ISO image.

After searching I found that I need to modify my plist.info to allow my boot camp to create a bootable USB (since normally it doesn't have the option to create the USB for my model since it came with a disk drive).

After doing so and seemingly having a fine (but long) install process onto the USB. I told boot camp how much space to partition windows on and hit install.

Then the computer restarted. When it came back up it was stuck on a grey apple logo screen forever (I waited 15 minutes to ensure it wasn't just "thinking"). I force restarted and the next time it turned on it got stuck on the grey logo for a bit but then proceeded to go to a black screen that said " No bootable device - please insert a bootable device and hit any key". I tried hitting keys with he USB in but nothing happened.

I had to eventually remove the USB and reset PRAM to get it to boot into osx again

Is there any way to install windows 7 from a usb on my macbook pro using boot camp?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## UPDATE

An improved procedure for installing Windows 7 can be found at **[Installing Windows 7 Pro 64 bit without DVD or Flash Drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225387/no-bootable-device-usb-2-0-macbook-pro-mid-2014/225521#225521)**

### Note:

The updated steps, for installing Windows 8.1 using the procedure given below, can be found [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/189335/any-solution-to-bootcamp-windows-8-1-with-macbook-pro-15-2010/189398#189398).

---

My hardware and software differs from yours. I will first document how I tested my answer and then try to adapt the answer to your needs. Since this is a fairly long answer, the adaption will be given as a separate answer.

My computer is an iMac (20-inch Mid 2007). The version of OS X is 10.10.5. I will be installing Windows 7 Professional SP1 64 Bit.
I have only one internal drive. It is a 1 TB hard disk using the Apple hybrid GUID partitioning scheme. Hybrid means Windows will see the drive as MBR partitioned, while OS X views the drive as GUID partitioned. I will be following Apple's recommendations and installing Window using the legacy BIOS. **I also have a working internal optical SuperDrive which is not used to install Windows.**

(Hint: For a better view, click on an image or open an image in a new window.)

1. Aquire the Boot Camp Support Software (the drivers). The software
   can either be downloaded using the Boot Camp Assistant, downloaded
   directly from the Web or copied off a OS X installation DVD. See
   [System requirements to install Windows on your Mac via Boot
   Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204048) for details. This procedure does **not** require the use of
   a flash drive. *If your Boot Camp Support Software is stored on a
   flash drive, then follow the special instructions given in certain
   step that follow.*
2. Make sure your firmware is up to date. See [EFI and SMC firmware
   updates for Intel-based Macs](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201518).
3. Download and install a free copy of [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org) from Oracle. I
   used VirtualBox, Version 5.0.0 r101573, Copyright © 2015.
4. Inside your "Documents" folder, create a folder named "VirtualBox".
   This is where you will keep the files created in the rest of the
   steps.
5. Create a MS-DOS (FAT) formatted partition to install Windows. You
   can use the Bootcamp Assistant, the Disk Utility, or commands
   (`distutil`, `gpt` and/or `fdisk`) entered in a Terminal window.
   Other third party tools, such as [`gdisk`](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/), can also be used.
   Give the label for this partition the name "BOOTCAMP".
6. Determine the disk and partition numbers of the partition named
   "BOOTCAMP". To do this, highlight the partition in the Disk Utility
   application and click the "Info" button. A popup window should
   appear. The values shown will be used in the next step.

   [image]

   The information, in this pop up window, shows the disk and partition
   numbers are 0 and 4, respectively. If your numbers are different,
   you will need to substitute your numbers in the rest of the steps.
   **If your partition number is greater than 4, then you can not install Windows on this partition.** (*Technically, this may not be
   true, but it is beyond the scope of this answer to explain how to do
   so.*)

   [image]

   Do **not** close the popup window.
7. Open the Terminal application and enter the following commands in
   the Terminal window. This will set variables to be used in later
   commands. In the next command, replace `α` with the "Disk Number"
   shown in the Disk Utility popup window. The usual value for `α` is
   `0`.

   ```
   DISK0=/dev/diskα
   ```

   In the next command, replace `β` with the "Partition Number" shown
   in the Disk Utility popup window. The usual value for `β` is `4`.

   ```
   PARTITION=β
   ```

   The next command sets the variable `PARTID` to the disk identifier of
   the partition. This should be the same as the "Disk Identifier"
   shown in the Disk Utility popup window. The usual value for `PARTID`
   is `disk0s4`.

   ```
   PARTID="$DISK0"s"$PARTITION"
   ```

   Note: the letter `s` is lower case.

   Close the Disk Utility popup window.
8. With the Disk Utility application still open, select "File→New→Blank
   Disk Image..." from the menu bar. In the popup window, enter the
   values shown below. Note: "Where:" should be the "VirtualBox" folder
   created in Step 4. *If the Boot Camp Support Software is stored on a
   flash drive, you can use the default "Size:" of "100 MB".*

   Save As: bcssoftware
   Tags:
   Where: VirtualBox
   Name: BCSSOFTWARE
   Size: Custom... (1.5 GB)
   Format: MS-DOS (FAT)
   Encryption: none
   Partitions: Single partition -  Master Boot Record Partition Map
   Image Format: read/write disk image

   The popup window should appear as shown below.

   [image]

   Click the "Create" button.
9. Determine the disk number of the partition named "BCSSOFTWARE". To
   do this, highlight the partition in the Disk Utility application and
   click the "Info" button. A popup window should appear. The values
   shown will be used in the next step.

   [image]

   The information, in this pop up window, shows the disk number is 1.
   If your number is different, you will need to substitute your number
   in the rest of the steps.

   [image]

   Do **not** close the popup window.
10. Using the same Terminal window, enter the following to set the
    variable `DISK1`. Replace `γ` with the "Disk Number" shown in the
    Disk Utility popup window. The usual value for `γ` is `1`.

    ```
    DISK1=/dev/diskγ
    ```

    **Quit the Disk Utility.**
11. Copy the Boot Camp Support Software to to the partition labeled
    "BCSSOFTWARE". I used the Finder application to do this. *You can
    skip this step, if this software is already stored on a flash
    drive.*
12. Mark your partition as active in the MBR by entering the following
    in the same Terminal window. The input for the interactive command
    `fdisk` is taken from the variable `INPUT`. If a password  is asked
    for, enter it.

    ```
    INPUT=$(printf  "f  $PARTITION\nw\ny\nq")
    sudo  fdisk  -e  $DISK0  <<<"$INPUT"
    ```

    Note: To display the value for the variable `INPUT`, use the
    command `echo "$INPUT"`.
13. Allow VirtualBox read/write access to your physical partition by
    entering the following commands in the same Terminal window. If a
    password is asked for, enter it.

    ```
    diskutil  unmount  $PARTID 
    sudo  chmod  go+rw  $PARTID
    ```

    This will allow VirtualBox to install Windows on your physical
    partition. **Note: This access will only last until OS X is
    rebooted.**
14. Create the files that map the virtual partition and disk to the
    physical partition and disk image. In the same Terminal window,
    enter the following commands.

    ```
    cd  ~/documents/virtualbox
    sudo  vboxmanage  internalcommands  createrawvmdk  -filename  "$PWD/bootcamp.vmdk"  -rawdisk  $DISK0  -partitions  $PARTITION
    sudo  chown  $USER  bootcamp*.vmdk
    diskutil unmountDisk $DISK1
    vboxmanage  internalcommands  createrawvmdk  -filename  "$PWD/bcssoftware.vmdk"  -rawdisk  $DISK1
    ```

    > Note: If a password is asked for, enter it.
15. Open the VirtualBox application and click on icon above the New
    label. Enter or select the values shown below, then click the
    "Continue" button.

    [image]

    Use the default settings  except for the hard drive. Choose the
    "Use an existing virtual hard  drive file" button. Navigate to the
    VirtualBox folder created in  step 4. Open the "bootcamp.vmdk"
    file. Your window should appear similar to what is shown below.

    [image]

    Click the "Create" button.
16. Enter  the following command in the same Terminal window.

    ```
    diskutil  unmountDisk  $DISK1
    ```

    Return to the VirtualBox application's "Oracle VM Virtual Manager"
    window and click on the  icon above the "Settings" label. Next,
    click on the icon above the "Storage" label. Right click on
    "Controller: SATA" and select "Add  Hard Disk". Choose existing
    disk by opening the file "bcssoftware.vmdk" stored in the folder
    created in step 14. The attachment "bcssoftware.vmdk" should appear
    as shown below.

    [image: a16]

    ***It has been reported by other users that the "Use Host I/O Cache" box needs to be checked on if VirtualBox boot fails with error `VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED`.***
17. Highlight the Empty CD/DVD and select "Choose a virtual CD/DVD
    file..." to attach your Windows installation iso  file. (Hint: Look
    for the CD/DVD icons)

    [image: a17]

    Click OK to close the  window. Your "Oracle VM Virtual Manager"
    window should appear similar to what is shown below.

    [image: a18]
18. Before clicking the icon above the "Start" label to begin installing
    Windows, enter the following command in the same Terminal window.

    ```
    diskutil unmountDisk $DISK1
    ```
19. When you reach the window shown below, select "Custom (advanced)".

    [image]

    In the next window, click on "Drive options (advanced)".

    [image]

    Select the "BOOTCAMP" partition and click on "Format". The error
    message shown below will disappear. Click on "Next" to continue
    installation.

    [image]
20. The rest the virtual machine installation will be repeated again
    after booting Windows on the physical machine. Use the provided
    answers when the following windows first appear. When asked a
    second time, you can provide your own answers.

    When the following window first appears, I would enter the Product
    Key and uncheck the "Automatically active Windows when I'm online"
    box.

    [image]

    To be safe, I would not let any updates download or install until
    after the Boot Camp Support Software (the drivers) is installed.
    Therefore, I would click on "Ask me later" in the window shown
    below.

    [image]

    VirtualBox creates a virtual Public network for your virtual
    machine. Therefore I would click on "Public network" in the window
    shown below.

    [image]
21. Once the installation has completed on the virtual machine, you
    need complete the following instructions to make a copy the MBR
    bootstrap code. From the Start Menu, select "Computer" to open a
    window containing the hard disk drives and devices with removable
    storage. Determine the drive letters for  the hard disk drive
    labeled "BCSSOFTWARE" and the CD (optical)   drive. The image below
    shows the drive letters on my computer are  `D:` and `G:`,
    respectively. Your drive letters may differ from mine.

    [image]

    Close the window and open a Command  Prompt window run as an
    administrator. Select "Start Menu→All  Programs→Accessories",
    then right click on "Command Prompt" and  select "Run as
    administrator", as shown in the image below.

    [image]

    In the Command Prompt  window, enter the command shown below. If
    necessary, substitute your drive letters for `G:` and `D:`.

    ```
    G:\BOOT\BOOTSECT  /NT60  D:  /MBR
    ```

    The results of running this command on my computer are shown below.

    [image]

    Close the Command Prompt window.
22. Copy the Boot Camp Support Software from the partition labeled
    "BCSSOFTWARE" to the "C:\Users\Public\Public Documents" folder. I
    used the Windows  Explorer to do this. *You can skip this step, if
    this software is already stored on a flash drive.*
23. You need to prepare Windows to run on your physical Mac. Open the
    Windows  Explorer and navigate to the "C:\Windows\System32\sysprep"
    folder. Open the "sysprep" application. Select "Enter System
    Out-of-Box Experience (OOBE)", "Generalize" and "Shutdown" as shown
    below. Click OK and wait for the virtual machine to shutdown.

    [image]
24. Once the virtual machine has shutdown, quit VirtualBox. Enter the
    following in the same Terminal window. These commands will update
    the MBR bootstrap code, set the Windows partition identifier to 7
    in the MBR and then mount the partition. The input for the
    interactive command `fdisk` is taken  from the variable `INPUT`. If
    a password is asked for, enter it.

    ```
    sudo  fdisk  -u  -y  -f  $DISK1  $DISK0
    INPUT=$(printf  "s  $PARTITION\n7\nw\ny\nq")
    sudo  fdisk  -e   $DISK0  <<<"$INPUT"
    diskutil  mount  $PARTID
    ```
25. Close all other applications. Open System Preferences and select
    "Startup Disk". Highlight the "Untitled Windows" icon and click the
    "Restart" button.

    [image]

    If something goes wrong, you will need to hold down the "option" key
    at startup to return to OS X. Hopefully, nothing will go wrong and
    Windows will start.
26. When Windows finishing installing, install the Boot Camp Support
    Software (the drivers). This software is either in the
    "C:\Users\Public\Public Documents" folder, or on a flash drive.

### COMMENTS

On OS X El Capitan (10.11) the System Integrity Protection does not allow editing the MBR with `fdisk`, so disable SIP [following these instructions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/208481/19237) for the duration of the install.

I ended up having to create two user accounts. If you only want one account, you have two options. First, delete one of the accounts. Second, disable one of the accounts so it will not appear. The former can be accomplished from the Control Panel, the latter requires entering the command `control  userpasswords2` in a Command Prompt window. For example, below is the window were one can enable or disable the rpj account. If you need help let me know.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the awesome help! I will try this all out this weekend and report back with (hopeful) success.

Comment: David, thanks a million! I could not for the life of me figure out how to get around the blank screen. This solution worked out very well and was only slightly more complicated than a standard Bootcamp install. This helped me fix the issue that I was hitting in this Apple Support Forum thread: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6448031?start=30&tstart=0

Comment: Man, I don't know, how are you doing this. You didn't guess this things, you know them all. Greatly appreciate your help, it's just WOW!

Comment: Amazing work. Would it be possible to skip the hybrid MBR/EFI step and do an EFI-only install on a later model Mac and/or later version of Windows? That should allow more than 4 partitions, correct?

Comment: @Evan: If you have Mac that supports an EFI install of Windows, then that model would also support using a flash drive to install Windows. In such a case, there would be little point to using the above answer. You would be better off following Apple's published Windows installation procedures.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Gotcha. I was looking more for a way to run a natively installed OS as a VirtualBox Guest. I tried it out this weekend without success and ended up natively installing Windows instead. After reading your comment I experimented a bit and managed to get EFI to boot to ReFind (ie my custom bootloader) but it bluescreens when I launch Windows. Getting it to work with EFI required adding the boot partition /dev/disk0s1 to the vmdk with rw permissions. I'm going to try Linux next.

Comment: One other minor addition. If the VM crashes with an error when you try to load it, try setting 'Use Host IO Cache' in the storage settings.

Comment: @Evan: Why not post a question explaining what you are trying to do? I believe VirtualBox emulates hardware which is different from the physical hardware of the host machine. Therefore, I don't think you can run a natively installed Windows as a VirtualBox guest. I am confused by your last post. ReFind is a boot manager not a boot loader. It would also help if you could give the model of your Mac and the version of Windows and Linux.

Comment: Wonderful tutorial! I got a "VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED" error when trying to boot with VirtualBox 5. I needed to enable "Use Host I/O Cache" in the Sata options and it worked.

Comment: Excellent tutorial and worked perfectly when even buying an external optical drive failed me (internal one failed). My only suggestion would be to add comments when going through terminal to expect some false positive errors. (I got really confused during these).

Comment: @ghostof101: Feel free to edit my answer and add some comments. The changes will be reviewed (and possibly edited) before being made viewable by others.

Comment: @ghostof101: Actually, these instructions have been replaced by a sightly improved procedure. See: [Installing Windows 7 Pro 64 bit without DVD or Flash Drive](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225387/no-bootable-device-usb-2-0-macbook-pro-mid-2014/225521#225521). Basically, the new procedure does not require installing Windows 7 twice. Instead, VirtualBox is only used to copy the installation software to the Boot Camp partition. The installation of Windows then takes place without using a virtual environment.

Comment: @davidanderson Ah! Thank you kindly. I had a member of my team that was having the exact same version. Nice to know he won't have to do quite as many hoops as I did. ;)

Comment: I get a problem with Step 8: http://imgur.com/a/0pAfx When creating an New Blank Image I get Disk Utility error -61

Comment: @Sean: Are you sure you selected the correct folder and that the volume had enough free space? See [this link](http://imgur.com/5k8PdLZ) for an expanded view of the image shown in Step 8. This new image was taken using OS X 10.11.6. Are you using a different version of OS X?

Comment: @David Anderson yes that was the problem I wasn't creating a VirtualBox folder and was selecting the drive instead. I followed the instructions but still got the dreaded "No bootable devices" error. Installing http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/sip.html as a Boot Manager helped to force find the Windows installation and boot from it.

Comment: @Sean: By installing and using rEFInd, one can replace many of the steps in the procedure. If you had to use rEFInd to finish the installation, then you probably just made an error applying one or more of the posted steps. For example, using rEFInd can eliminate the need to create and use the BCSSOFTWARE partition.

Comment: Sadly can't get my external SSD to show as a boot option when restarting with options. Trying to manually set it as a startup disk returns "The bless tool was unable to set the current boot disk."

Comment: Thank you so much, Crazy genius @David Anderson. I managed to install WIndows7 64 on my iMac 27' Mid 2010 on the third try. My first two attempts failed at the step to open command line tool when installing windows. I get an error when click "Repair this computer". I guess it's a problem of the windows installation ISO, as i used a different iso i finally get passed the error. Oh By the way i use Mac os X 10.11 named El Capitan

Comment: Step 23 (sysprep) failed for me with a "fatal error" (using Win7ProSP1-x64-EN-X17-59186). The log in c:\windows\system32\sysprep\panther\setuperr.log mentioned the cause, which came from "drmv2ctl.dll". That dll is apparently related to Windows Media Player. Workaround found on MS technet: execute services.msc, find "Windows Media Player Network Sharing Service", and change its startup type to "Disabled", then stop it. Run sysprep again, and it should now work :-)

Comment: So, I have MBA 6,2, I encountered 2 problems, 1 solved, 1 stuck.
1st problem, "Operation not permitted" from `sudo  fdisk  -e  $DISK0  <<<"$INPUT"`, solved by disable the csrutil.
2nd problem, Stuck at Booting up the BootCamp, it says "Press any key to boot from CD or DVD", tried severals ISO which are just fine, tried win7 and win10, it just stuck there.

Comment: @CuriousNewbie: Why are you using this answer? A MacBookAir6,2 is a Mid-2013 or Early-2014 MacBook Air. You should be able to install 64-bit Windows 7, 8, 8.1 or 10 by using the Boot Camp Assistant and a USB flash drive. Also, I would assume Windows 10 should UEFI boot on your model Mac and this answer would install a BIOS booting Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing it, it's not elegant but it will work.

Download and install [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and install Windows on it from your .ISO file. This will verify your .ISO is working. Once you've got Windows installed, download [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/). This will create a bootable USB drive that *will* boot your MacBook, assuming the .ISO is good to begin with. Once that's done you can bin the virtual machine and Virtualbox, ready to install Windows for real on the Boot Camp partition (if that's where it's going).

It's worth noting you don't need to use Boot Camp if Windows is going onto a drive of its own - BC is designed to create a hybrid partition table that will allow OS X and Windows to co-exist, and simply isn't needed if the OSes live on separate drives.

Comment: I'm  a tad confused by your method. I know my iso works because I used it on parallels and then decided I would rather have a real install instead of a virtual machine. So from here I should use Rufus to make a bootable USB? And then what? Use boot camp with the Rufus USB? How do I get the windows compatibility tools that apple provides to get the touch pad and other things working?

Comment: If you've an existing VM then yes, download Rufus and use that to create your bootable USB device. Whatever method you used to create your original USB installer obviously didn't work, I've Rufus many times and it's very effective at creating bootable USB devices. Once you've done that you will be able to startup from the USB stick using the boot selector and install Win 7 as if it was on a DVD.

Comment: As for compatibility, simply download the Boot Camp driver pack for your MacBook, copy to a USB device and install under Windows.

Comment: also when windows is installed on the separate disk how do i choose which my computer will boot into?

Comment: OS X offers **Startup Disk** to set the preferred default OS, Windows will offer the same option once the Boot Camp drivers have been installed. You also have the startup boot selector, hold **Option** when you hear the Mac startup chime. Whether you use the System Preference pane or the startup boot selector, OS X will list all available bootable disks.

Comment: @ScunnerDarkly: Are you positive that windows can be installed on a 2010 MBP using a USB flash drive? I have a 2007 iMac and I tried virtually every combination of Rufus options. I tried modifying the Boot Camp Assistance to create the flash drive installer. This flash drive did not work. I tried the Windows 7 flash drive installer from Microsoft with no luck. I installed rEFInd and it would sometime detect the flash drive under certain formats, but never successfully started to install.

Comment: @David Anderson: I've not tried on a 2010 model, boot support does seem to vary quite a bit between MacBook generations. I've a 2011 MBP 15" that doesn't want to know about Rufus-created USB versions of Windows, Mint/Ubuntu Linux or one of my favourite tools, Parted Magic - yet my 2012 MBP 13" boots *all* of these absolutely fine from USB. Incidentally, the Boot Camp utility that ships with 10.9 gives the option to create a USB Windows installer regardless of whether the host Mac has an optical drive or not, so this may be worth a try if you've tried everything else...

Comment: Great guide. A few notes: The Bootcamp drivers don't need to be on a *flash* drive. Any regular external USB drive works. To write the hex data to the drive, you could also use my tool "iBored" (http://apps.tempel.org/iBored/).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by disabling System Integrity Protection (rootless) a new security feature in El Captain.

1. Restart and enter recovery partition by holding down keys: `Command + R`
2. Open Terminal from menu and enter `csrutil disable; reboot`
3. Restart hold key `R` and select El Captain partition.
4. Open bootcamp and re-format/install Windows

This then worked this time automatically restarting windows.