# "No bootable device insert disk and press any key" boot camp

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows

I am trying to install windows 7 using bootcamp on my Macbook Pro running Yosemite. Everything goes well except when it is done with partitioning the hard drive. When it boots to windows a black screen appears with the message "No bootable device insert disk and press any key." When I press a key nothing happens. I tried restarting it and holding down the option key but only the Macintosh HD appears.

**EDIT:**

I now burned the iso file to a dvd but when i try to boot into Windows it gets stuck on "windows is loading files." After that an error message appears.

Here is a picture:

[image]

Comment: What is the model identifier or year/screen_size of your Macbook Pro? Are you installing using a DVD or USB flash drive? If a flash drive, how did you create it?

Comment: @DavidAnderson I am using a Early 2011 13" Macbook Pro. I am using a 32 gb flash drive to install. I create it by opening Boot Camp Assistance and checking all 3 boxes and then selecting the ISO file.

Comment: I've never been able to get Windows on a machine with a Superdrive other than by DVD, not USB stick

Comment: @Tetsujin Should I try burning the iso to a dvd and then try to install Windows?

Comment: I think it may be worth it, yes; I think you can create it directly in bootcamp, though it's been a long time since i did it myself. I found a guide here - http://laptops.eng.uci.edu/instructional-computing/incoming-students/information-for-mac-users/usb-drive but I'm not sure how up to date it is. Wish you luck on your coaster-count ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin See my edit

Comment: @DavidAnderson See my edit

Comment: I find it odd that you were able to burn a DVD, but not be able to boot to it. I say this because I believe the Disk Utility application verifies the DVD after burning it. Anyway, if you can not install using a DVD or USB flash drive, then you will have to use a free copy of VirtualBox. You will **not** be using VirtualBox to run Windows 7, just to install Windows 7. The instructions are given [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179486/boot-camp-install-of-windows-7-issue-no-bootable-devices/180263#180263). (Let me know, if you plan to update to Windows 10 or run both 7 and 10)