# Issue installing Win 7 on Mac

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows

I have been following [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225387/no-bootable-device-usb-2-0-macbook-pro-mid-2014/225521#225521) to install Windows in Boot Camp.

Seemed to work absolutely fine until the command e:\setup in step 9. When this command is run "The subsystem needed to support the image type is not present." is returned.

`setup.exe` is available in the directory though.

I'm unsure on how to proceed from here, as it has been some years since I last fiddled under the hood of a windows product.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Worked out what the issue was. Double checked the specs of my machine and realised it was a mid 2007 model. Upon checking with Apple using the link in the linked answer I found the specific bootcamp file and that I had to use Win 7 32bit. Altering these files and using the correct disk image allows the installation to start.

Thanks for your help David.

Ross

Comment: You may be correct, but the funny thing is I created and tested the procedure to install 64 bit Windows 7 Pro using a 20 inch, mid 2007 iMac. Apple reports that my machine must install the 32 bit version of Windows, but I have been able to install the 64 bit version of Windows 7, 8, 8.1 and 10.  If you are using the same "Boot Camp Support Software" (Version 4.0.4033) that I am, then I can tell you that this software is not used until step 10. On the other hand, our machines are different, so just because I can install 64 bit Windows does not guarantee you can.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the error you reported to have. I could not. If you feel you have not made a mistake somewhere, I would recommend trying to install Windows using the previous method given [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179486/boot-camp-install-of-windows-7-issue-no-bootable-devices/180263#180263).