# Install Windows 8.1 on Mac 2011

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I'm trying to install Windows 8.1 on my Macbook Pro 15" 2011 model running El Capitan

I'm using Boot Camp and a 8GB USB

First of all i only have two options starting Boot Camp and not three like i see in a lot of guides about how to do the install.

My options are:

1. Get the newest software for Windows support from Apple
2. Install Windows 7 or newer

After i've marked the two options the download runs, but after it's done i get a message telling me that the installationdisk doesn't exists.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried burning the Window 8.1 iso to a DVD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually with the 2011 and later Mac models, you have to use a DVD to install Windows using the Boot Camp Assistant. I would recommend a RW DVD. They take longer to burn, but are reusable. If your optical drive does not work, post a comment and you can discuss other ways to install Windows.

> Note: You will still need a USB flash drive to hold the "Boot Camp Support Software" from Apple.

Comment: Well. My optimal drive doesn't work, but i ordered a replacement. But if there's a way to install without i'd love to hear about it.

Comment: @Christoffer: There are many methods for installing without using a optical (DVD) drive. See [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179486/boot-camp-install-of-windows-7-issue-no-bootable-devices/180263#180263) for some examples.