# Can't detect bootcamp partition on windows installation

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I followed this site for the instruction on how to boot up windows on my bootcamp partition: https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/install-windows-on-mac/

Now I'm stuck in the VM ware installation.
The setup runs but once I get to the formatting page, the installer can't detect any storage.
I tried formatting  bootcamp to and ntfs using ntfs 3g but it still won't work. (I'm really not sure what I'm doing at this point)

Right now, I have the VM and the bootcamp partition of 60 Gb formatted in Fat32.

Now, I'm not sure if this solution will work, but how can I make the installer detect my storage so I can proceed to the next steps?

I have a macbook 4,1 early 2008 running on OS X lion (10.7.5) and I'm using VMware 6
I'm trying to install win7_32bit

Thanks in advance for those who will offer some help :)

Answer (score 1):

I do not have VMware 6 so I can not post a direct answer to your question. I believe the reference link given in your question has left out many steps that need to be taken in order for you to succeed. There is two previous answers posted here at Ask Different where VirtualBox was used to install 64 bit Windows 7 on older Macs. The links are given below.

[Boot camp install of Windows 7 issue, no bootable devices](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179486/boot-camp-install-of-windows-7-issue-no-bootable-devices)
[No bootable device USB 2.0 MacBook Pro mid 2014](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225387/no-bootable-device-usb-2-0-macbook-pro-mid-2014)

VirtualBox is a free product. Since you are using OS X lion, you would have to install an older version of VirtualBox.