# Can't mount Windows Boot Camp & USB on a MacBook OS X Yosemite 10.10.2

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows

I have a MacBook Pro (Late 2011) 13 inch running OS X Yosemite 10.10.2 and I wanted to mount Windows 8 professional via Boot Camp with USB drive.

I've already watched a ton of tutorials and read a whole heck of stuff, but I see only one difference in my problem so far. I have a 16 GB usb drive, a Windows ISO file and all the rest of the stuff required.

But the only thing that I meet so far is that when everybody else I've seen doing this open Boot Camp Assistant, they have three choices right away. Yet, what I have is only 2 choice variants and my Boot Camp Assistant for some reason lacks the "Create a Windows 7 or later install disk" choice button.

How can I mount Windows in this case, or what am I supposed to do?

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your bootcamp window with the options?

Comment: Do you have a DVD drive? If so, use the Disk Utility to burn the iso to a DVD.

Comment: @dennismuys God, its in russian but whatever
The first option says "download the latest support software from Apple" and the second one says "install windows 7 or later" [link](http://imgur.com/Bfqgh4v)

Comment: @DavidAnderson So, you mean I actually need a clean DVD which is 6,5gb+? What if I just don't have one?
I tried creating a disk image via Daemon tools, but later when it got to restarting there was the "no boot device found" error on the screen.

Comment: Which is correct: 1. You do not know how to create a DVD. 2. You can not create a DVD, because of a hardware problem 3. You do not have a blank DVD

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

MacBook Pro (Late 2011) = MacBookPro8,1

According to [MacBook Pro (13-inch, Late 2011) - Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP645?locale=en_US) this has a 8x slot-loading SuperDrive.

You should use your DVD drive to install Windows.

According to the Info.plist for the Boot Camp Assistant, your model is one of the "PreUSB Boot Supported Models". The usually means if you create a USB flash drive installer by any method, you will not be able to boot from it.

You also have a one of the "PreUEFI Models". This means you should install using using a BIOS/MBR boot method.

In the event, you can not install using a DVD, you can try using Virtual Box. The instructions are given [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/189335/any-solution-to-bootcamp-windows-8-1-with-macbook-pro-15-2010/189398#189398). This will install Windows to your internal disk without the use of a DVD.

Comment: Oh well... 
Thanks at least for something, though!

Comment: Yeah, I've used Virtual Box already. I need Windows for some very high CPU-consuming programs like FL Studio and Sony Vegas6, so running two operating systems at time just isn't a way cause the computer becomes veeeeeery slow.

Comment: @Dynasty: You DO NOT UNDERSTAND. You are not going to run Windows using Virtual Box. You only use Virtual Box to install windows. You will be running windows the normal way. Read the procedure. If you have any problems, let me know. I wrote the procedure.