# How to install Windows 8 on a MacBook Pro with OS X Yosemite, using Boot Camp, without a USB drive or DVD

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, usb, startup, windows

The title covers most of my question. I am relatively new to the Mac world, and came across Boot Camp, which can dual-boot Windows, which seems pretty cool. I have read through many Boot Camp guides, and know that a USB drive must be used (my new Mac does not have a CD/DVD drive). I do not have any USB drives at the moment that I want to format, and I would like to know if there is a way to do it without a USB drive. I know that it may be harder or impossible to do it without a USB drive, and I can back up my USB, but I would like to be able to install Windows without a USB drive. **Alternate question: if I do format my flash drive (64 gb), will I be able to store other files on it, or will it only work with my Windows OS?**

Comment: That is not possible !

Comment: [Here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/189335/any-solution-to-bootcamp-windows-8-1-with-macbook-pro-15-2010/189398#189398) is a procedure for installing without using a USB flash drive or a DVD. It is meant for older models where the DVD drive has either been removed or no longer works.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thank you! I actually decided on VirtualBox a few hours after asking my question, as I realized BootCamp only supports Windows, as well as the intricacies doing it without a USB. I also decided to install Ubuntu on it as well as Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Windows on a Mac via Boot Camp you only have two choices, DVD or USB.  You also need a Windows DVD (Full Install Media not Upgrade Media) or an ISO Image of the Windows DVD to create the USB Installer via the Boot Camp Assistant.

Yes, you'll be able to use the USB drive to store other files after the Boot Camp Assistant has written the files necessary to install Windows via USB.  However you need to first backup what you have on the USB drive as it will be removed in the process of creating the USB Windows Installer.

- Note: For use in installing Windows the USB drive will be formatted FAT32 and as such you'll not be able to store files over 4GB in size for use with the "*other files*" you want to have on the USB drive.

Comment: Thanks for that, I didn't want to waste my 64gb flash drive on just an OS. I don't think I have any single files that are 4gb large. Just a follow-up question: Let's say I have a game that I run from my flash drive on a computer. Would that still work, as the flash drive has now been formatted?

Comment: @VampireTooth, Anything you have on the USB drive needs to be **backed up off of the drive before using it to create the USB Windows Installer**.  It can then be placed back on the USB Drive after the Boot Camp Assistant does its thing or if you choose to do so after installing Windows you can restore it to how ever you had it before.

Answer (score 0):

Go to utilities click bootcamp follow the step by step instructions

Format the partitioned drive first

Give the partition at least 40GBs

Make sure you have a valid copy of windows

If you need more help here are a couple of videos with step by step instructions

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ShdKIMA7gz0 How to Install windows

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X9w3sFsiaA0 Make a Bootable usb